# Can we tell how far away is the source of gravitational wave from the chirp alone?

Tags: black-holes, gravitational-waves, ligo, chirp

From the analysis of chirp from Ligo and some other similar detector it is possible to tell the mass but can we also find out how far away too? or we need to look up into the sky and compare the energy wavelength of photon vs standard candle? What if the source is binary blackholes merger in a bootes void like region of space?

Comment: @RobJeffries: Yes,also is it possible for the inferred lumosity distance to be a lot different from the observation? If so which is more accurate?

Comment: What do you mean by "the observation"?

Comment: @RobJeffries: say a kilonova occurs, comparing the source distance based on the chirp picked up by ligo and other instruments vs the telescope which detects the photon.

Comment: Yes, that has been done and is referred to (with a link you can look at) in the duplicate.